# VueJS select depending of another select

Tags: vue.js

I have  countries and cities jsons that comes from backend. And I want to make in the vuejs when I select a country in the cities select to have the cities from that country.

I got stuck here and I have no idea how to bring the cities only for that country that is selected.

Can someone please give me a little help?

Countries JSON

GET /languages/countries (list of countries)

```
{
    "errorCode": 0,
    "errorMessage": null,
    "contries": [
        {
            "errorCode": 0,
            "errorMessage": null,
            "rid": "1",
            "sortname": "AF",
            "name": "Afghanistan",
            "phonecode": 93,
            "links": []
        },
        {
            "errorCode": 0,
            "errorMessage": null,
            "rid": "2",
            "sortname": "AL",
            "name": "Albania",
            "phonecode": 355,
            "links": []
        },
        {
            "errorCode": 0,
            "errorMessage": null,
            "rid": "3",
            "sortname": "DZ",
            "name": "Algeria",
            "phonecode": 213,
            "links": []
        }
    ],
    "links": []
}
```

Cities JSON

GET /languages/countries/1 (list of cities for country with id =1)

```
{
  "errorCode": 0,
  "errorMessage": null,
  "cities": [
    {
      "errorCode": 0,
      "errorMessage": null,
      "rid": "33129",
      "name": "Abrud",
      "stateId": 2934,
      "links": []
    },
    {
      "errorCode": 0,
      "errorMessage": null,
      "rid": "33130",
      "name": "Aiud",
      "stateId": 2934,
      "links": []
    },
    {
      "errorCode": 0,
      "errorMessage": null,
      "rid": "33131",
      "name": "Alba Iulia",
      "stateId": 2934,
      "links": []
    }
  ],
  "links": []
}
```

VueJS script

```
export default {
    data() {
      return {
        users: {},
        countries: {},
        cities: {}
      }
    },
    created() {
      this.getUsers();
      this.getCountries();
      this.getCities();
    },
    methods: {
      getUsers() {
        this.$http.get("/user")
          .then((response) => {
            this.users = response.data.users;
          })
      },
      getCountries() {
        this.$http.get("/languages/countries")
          .then((response) => {
            this.countries = response.data.contries;
          })
      },
      getCities() {
        this.$http.get("/languages/countries/"+this.country.rid)
          .then((response) => {
            this.cities = response.data.cities;
          })
      },
    },
      components: {
            appMenu: Menu
        }
    }
```

HTML Selects

```
 <div class="form-group">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 pz-rel">
      <label class="eda-form-label" for="country">COUNTRY</label>
      <select class="eda-form-input">
        <option v-for="country in countries" :value="country.name">{{country.name}}</option>
      </select>
      <i class="ti-angle-down icons-for-select"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 pz-rel">
      <label class="eda-form-label" for="city">CITY</label>
      <select class="eda-form-input">
        <option v-for="city in cities" :value="city.name">{{city.name}}</option>
      </select>
      <i class="ti-angle-down icons-for-select"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So in the first step you get all the countries.
However with the rest call for the cities you described, you cannot get all the cities for all countries at once.
So as a result I would fetch the cities for the currently selected country

**EDIT** 
the line with `<option>` must be changed. Currently the value will be bound to the `name`. So it must be changed from `< ... :value="country.name" to :value="country">`

```
<select class="eda-form-input" v-model='selectedCountry' v-on:change='getCities(selectedCountry.rid)'>
  <option v-for="country in countries" :value="country"> <!-- here -->
    {{country.name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

Above there is one more data variable now `selectedCountry`, which will hold the currently selected country. So this also must be declared in `data`.

```
data() {
  return {
    users: {},
    countries: {},
    cities: {},
    selectedCountry: null
  }
},
```

And give the method getCities a parameter for the country:

```
 getCities(countryId) {
    this.$http.get("/languages/countries/"+countryId)
      .then((response) => {
        this.cities = response.data.cities;
      })
  },
```

Comment: For I don't know what reasons doesn't work. Your login it's very good, but in the console I get undefined for id in the request url : `www.example.com/languages/countries/undefined`

Comment: Did you also delete this line `this.getCities();` in the `created()` lifecycle hook?

Comment: Yes I deleted. The error is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rid' of undefined`. Somehow in the `getCities(countryId)` the `rid` from `selectedCountry.rid` doesn't come.

Comment: That error comes after I select the country. With `{{selectedCountry}}` I get the right country but not the rid.

Comment: I did like u said: `<select class="eda-form-input" v-model='selectedCountry' @change="getCities(selectedCountry.rid)">
                      <option v-for="country in countries" :value="country.name">{{country.name}}</option>
                    </select>{{selectedCountry}}`

Comment: My friend you are a genius. Thank you very much. You deserve 1.000.000 points for this answer :).

Comment: Works. Thank you. It's strange why I still get in the console this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rid' of undefined` when I select the country.

Comment: Do you know why or how can I hide it?

Comment: In `{{selectedCountry}}` I get correct: `{ "errorCode": 0, "errorMessage": null, "rid": "14", "sortname": "AT", "name": "Austria", "phonecode": 43, "links": [] }`. Why my friend I still get that error :) ?

Comment: Is that error coming every time you change the country or just once?

Comment: Only once after I refresh the page

Comment: I mean when I enter on that page I get in the console that error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153383/discussion-between-d-f-and-john-smith).